Duplicate rows in tables linked by FKs, maintaining old association on new records
Im trying to duplicate rows in my tables while keeping the same link between them.
Im using PGSQL. I will explain with examples.
Employer table:



ID
Name
ServiceProviderID
UpdatedAt




1
Apple
10
2024-04-24 15:35:24


2
Microsoft
11
2024-05-16 19:00:58


3
Meta
11
2024-05-08 17:03:08



I want to duplicate specific rows, based on its ServiceProviderID while changing only ServiceProviderID.
This is how I achieved it:
INSERT INTO employer (name, service_provider_id, updated_at)
SELECT name, 999, updated_at
FROM employer
WHERE service_provider_id = 11
RETURNING id;

It will result in both Microsoft and Meta rows being duplicated, because they have ServiceProviderID=11, but with ServiceProviderID changed to 999
However, on my Worker table, I cant figure out how to map them to the newly inserted Employer.
Worker table:



ID
Name
ServiceProviderID
EmployerID




1
James Bond
10
1


2
Darth Vader
11
2


3
Marceline Abdr
11
3



If I run below code:
INSERT INTO worker (name, service_provider_id, employer_id)
SELECT name, 999, employer_id
FROM worker
WHERE service_provider_id = 11
RETURNING id;

The employer_id will still be the same it was on the original worker row. But I need it to be the newly inserted employer_id it was associated to. How can I do that?

Please show the exact CREATE TABLE employer script. And always your version of Postgres.

Is there possibly a UNIQUE constraint/index on (name, service_provider_id) for the table employer? If so, you could use some subselect to get the new employer_id from the old one like this: (SELECT id FROM employer e_new WHERE e_new.service_provider_id =  999 AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM employer e_old WHERE e_old.id = w.employer_id AND e_old.name = e_new.name)) (where I used w as an alias for the worker table).

The challenge is to link old employer.id to new employer.id - which can be challenging indeed because the rest of the row is not necessarily unique.
There are ways to resolve even duplicate entries. But it's much cheaper and more elegant to sidestep this potential hurdle by generating prospective IDs manually, with the good old nextval() function. Do it all in a single statement with CTEs:
WITH sel_e AS (
   SELECT *
        , nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('employer', 'id')) AS new_id  -- !!!
   FROM   employer e2
   WHERE  service_provider_id = 11
   )
, ins_e AS (   
   INSERT INTO employer
         (    id, name, service_provider_id, updated_at)
   SELECT new_id, name, 999                , updated_at
   FROM   sel_e
   WHERE  service_provider_id = 11
   )
INSERT INTO worker
      (  name, service_provider_id, employer_id)
SELECT w.name, 999                , s.new_id
FROM   worker w
LEFT   JOIN sel_e s ON s.id = w.employer_id
WHERE  w.service_provider_id = 11
RETURNING id;  -- optional

fiddle
See:

Reference value of serial column in another column during same INSERT
PostgreSQL next value of the sequences?

Assuming employer.id a serial or IDENTITY column, and you work with auto-generated IDs. (A proper table definition would clarify.)
See:

Auto increment table column

Aside: worker.service_provider_id seems redundant. (Always the same as the connected employer.service_provider_id?) Consider dropping the redundant column. You can identify workers via their employer_id.
